# Hercules: csrf exempt django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view:

```
@api_view(POST?)
@csrf_exempt
def user_login(request):
```

that adheres to the django rest framework.

How can I make this view csrf exempt?

I am trying to do API calls via iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this forum post helps clarify.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-rest-framework/JCf4MwNtfwM

According to it,

```
"REST framework views are CSRF exempt by default unless your using UserLoggedInAuthentication"
```

Are you actively experiencing a CSRF protection issue with REST Framework?

Joe